# FindRoot not varying all parameters

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find a root of a 6 by 6 system of nonlinear equations using the FindRoot command in the following code:

```
h = 18;
v = 195.06;
ab = Sqrt[h^2 + v^2];
data = {{0.9`, -((7 π)/60)}, 
        {4.1000000000000005`, -0.3455751918948773`}, 
        {5.7`, -0.3351032163829113`}};
sol = FindRoot[
  Join[{Sum[θe[
        i] (cd (-ab^2 + ad^2 + cd^2 + (x + data[[i]][[1]])^2)/
           Sqrt[4 ab^2 (ad^2 + cd^2) - (ab^2 + ad^2 + 
                cd^2 - (x + data[[i]][[1]])^2)^2] + ad), {i, 1, Length[data]}] == 0, 
    Sum[θe[
        i] (ad (-ab^2 + ad^2 + cd^2 + (x + data[[i]][[1]])^2)/
           Sqrt[4 ab^2 (ad^2 + cd^2) - (ab^2 + ad^2 + 
                cd^2 - (x + data[[i]][[1]])^2)^2] - cd), {i, 1, Length[data]}] == 0, 
    Sum[θe[i] (x + data[[i]][[1]])/
        Sqrt[4 ab^2 (ad^2 + cd^2) - (ab^2 + ad^2 + 
             cd^2 - (x + data[[i]][[1]])^2)^2], {i, 1, Length[data]}] == 0}, 
   Table[(x + data[[j]][[1]])^2 == (cd + 
         v Sin[data[[j]][[2]] - θe[j]] - 
         h Cos[data[[j]][[2]] - θe[j]])^2 + (ad - 
         v Cos[data[[j]][[2]] - θe[j]] - 
         h Sin[data[[j]][[2]] - θe[j]])^2, {j, 1, Length[data]}]], 
  Join[Table[{θe[i], 0}, {i, 1, Length[data]}], {{cd, 600}, {ad, 200}, {x, 500}}]]
```

The returned results are

```
{θe[1] -> 0.0000219133, θe[2] -> -0.000069204, 
 θe[3] -> 0.0000472906, cd -> 573.719, ad -> 292.804, x -> 500.}
```

Why doesn't Mathematica attempt to vary the final parameter? In particular, I notice that the order in which the parameters to be solved for are listed matters. Why is this? I expect the solutions to the equations to form a one-dimensional parameter subspace i.e. a list of at least one point in 6 by 6 space.

Comment: The answer given by `FindRoot` is a rule  indicating one point in the 6-dmensional parameterspace. Your question isn't clear for me!

Comment: Apply `// Rationalize[#, 0] &` after the joined equations and then `, WorkingPrecision -> 25` for FindRoot.  I get `{\[Theta]e[1] -> -6.419523211085895364108381*10^-43, \[Theta]e[2] -> 
  1.900988979264962771799009*10^-42, \[Theta]e[
   3] -> -1.259036661174191089227244*10^-42, 
 cd -> -35.59349035709196376298665, ad -> 148.5916866032443640780458, 
 x -> -126.1594385276357518639018}` with MMa Version 8.0.

Comment: With other starting values `{{cd, 100}, {ad, 100}, {x, 100}}` you get positive x,cd  `{\[Theta]e[1] -> 
  3.280532281533267133433754*10^-52, \[Theta]e[
   2] -> -4.927821217370111948985554*10^-52, \[Theta]e[3] -> 
  5.369668324145355168763241*10^-52, cd -> 137.3494109776652547298431,
  ad -> 66.94428703011580233796313, x -> 119.0261946726583709733849}`

Comment: What I mean is, if you're using FindRoot to solve one equation in one unknown, then the solution will be a new value for that unknown; if you're using FindRoot to solve two equations in one two unknowns, then the solution will be give new values for the two unknowns (provided the equations aren't consistent). By extension I would expect the FindRoot command to give new values of all six unknowns when solving a 6 by 6 system of equations (there's no consistency in the equations), yet the solution for the last parameter is the same as the initial starting value.